# Android: sound app crashes when background color is changed

Tags: android, audio, background, onclick

I have following problem. I have 3 buttons for changing the background color (blue, red and green respectively) and also 5 radio buttons that will play a sound when clicked. Both the background color change buttons as well as the sound radio buttons work completely fine independently. As soon as I put them together on one screen, the application will crash when one of the background color change button is selected. The problem lies in the RadioButton line, particularly here:

`RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;`

I don't know what to do against that error. Can somebody help me?

Here is the the code from the onClick Method:

```
               public void onClick(View v) {


            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);

               switch (v.getId()) 
               {
               case R.id.button1:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You switched the color to red!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                   rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

               break;
               case R.id.button2:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You switched the color to green!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                   rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
               break;
               case R.id.button3:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You switched the color to blue" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                   rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
               break;
               case R.id.cancel:
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This application will be closed!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                   finish();
               break;
               }


               //Perform action on clicks
                 RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;  

                 //get the user sound settings
                 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

                 //get current volume
                 float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                 //get maximum volume
                 float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                 float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

             //is the sound loaded already?
                 if(loaded) {
                     //play the sound
                     if (rb.getText().toString().equals("Clong!"))
                         gameAudio.play(soundIDs[0], volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                     else if (rb.getText().toString().equals("Hammering!"))
                         gameAudio.play(soundIDs[1], volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                     else if (rb.getText().toString().equals("Chainsaw Attack!"))
                         gameAudio.play(soundIDs[2], volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                     else if (rb.getText().toString().equals("Smoke alarm!"))
                         gameAudio.play(soundIDs[3], volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                     else if (rb.getText().toString().equals("Sharp the knife!"))
                         gameAudio.play(soundIDs[4], volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                 }

           }
```

Comment: POst logcat output too

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `onClick()` is fired for button presses... in that case, the `View v` is not a `RadioButton` but a button.

In that case, your logcat (which you should always include here) will show a ClassCastException.

Wrap the whole second part (dealing with the sound) in

```
if( v instanceof RadioButton ) {
    ... your code here
}
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: In the Java or Debug view, just look at the logcat tab and go from there. If you're debugging, you can generally double-click on the errors you see reported there, and Eclipse takes you to the offending line in your source.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//Perform action on clicks
if(v instanceof RadioButton)
{
                 RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;  
}else return;
```